# How can I install the BSD Game fish?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, apt-get

I heard of the package *bsdgames*. It should contains **fish**. But when I typed `fish` I was able to install a new shell called fish. So how can I install fish from the *bsdgames* package on a Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 0):

Install `bsdgames`, then run `go-fish`.